# Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str error with serializer field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using `Django 2.x` and `Django REST Framework`.

I have two models like

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class AmountGiven(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    amount = models.FloatField(help_text='Amount given to the contact')
    given_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

the **serializer.py** the file has serializers defined as

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'created', 'modified')

class AmountGivenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact = ContactSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = AmountGiven
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id', 'contact', 'amount', 'given_date', 'created'
        )
```

**views.py**

```
class AmountGivenViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AmountGivenSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        save_data = {}
        contact_pk = self.request.data.get('contact', None)
        if not contact_pk:
            raise ValidationError({'contact': ['Contact is required']})
        contact = Contact.objects.filter(
            user=self.request.user,
            pk=contact_pk
        ).first()
        if not contact:
            raise ValidationError({'contact': ['Contact does not exists']})
        save_data['contact'] = contact
        serializer.save(**save_data)
```

But when I add a new record to **AmountGiven** model and passing `contact` id in `contact` field

[image]

it is giving error as

```
{"contact":{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."]}}
```

When I remove `contact = ContactSerializer()` from **AmountGivenSerializer**, it works fine as expected but then in response as `depth` is set to 1, the contact data contains only model fields and not other property fields defined.

Comment: the contact serializer receiving uuid instead of json that's why its throwing errors, you have to use `primary key related field` instead of serializer  take a look at this https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield

Comment: I tried it, although it works but then there is no related `contact` data while getting `amount_given` and only have `id` in the `contact` field insted of whole data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of this request parsing pattern. From what I understand, you want to be able to see all the contact's details when you retrieve an `AmountGiven` object and at the same time be able to create and update `AmountGiven` by just providing the contact id.

So you can change your `AmountGiven` serializer to have 2 fields for the `contact` model field. Like this:

```
class AmountGivenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact_detail = ContactSerializer(source='contact', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = AmountGiven
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id', 'contact', 'contact_detail', 'amount', 'given_date', 'created'
        )
```

Note that the `contact_detail` field has a `source` attribute.

Now the default functionality for create and update should work out of the box (validation and everything).

And when you retrieve an `AmountGiven` object, you should get all the details for the contact in the `contact_detail` field.

## Update

I missed that you need to check whether the `Contact` belongs to a user (however, I don't see a `user` field on your `Contact` model, maybe you missed posting it). You can simplify that check:

```
class AmountGivenViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AmountGivenSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        contact = serializer.validated_data.get('contact')
        if contact.user != self.request.user:
            raise ValidationError({'contact': ['Not a valid contact']})
        serializer.save()
```

Comment: `perform_create` is there to check for whether contact id provided is of authenticated user or not. I tested it with removed `perform_create` and I was able to add `AmountGiven` record by passing `contact_id` that belongs to some other user. Every contact is associated to an user.

Comment: @AnujTBE Ah, in that case you can keep perform_create but you can get the contact with contact_pk = serializer.validated_data.get('contact').pk. Note that you don't have to create that `save_data` dictionary anymore.

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected. But how can I set `contact` read-only while updating?  `contact` is required only while creating a new record and that can not be changed later on while updating the record.

Comment: @AnujTBE you can override the `perform_update` method in your update view and always keep the old stored `contact` before saving.

Comment: could you please see these question...what is the problem in my code ...here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837158/invalid-data-expected-a-dictionary-but-got-list?noredirect=1#comment109374332_61837158

Answer (score 1):

Override the **`__init__()`** method of **`AmountGivenSerializer`** as

```
class AmountGivenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AmountGivenSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'view' in self.context and self.context['view'].action != 'create':
            self.fields.update({"contact": ContactSerializer()})

    class Meta:
        model = AmountGiven
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id', 'contact', 'amount', 'given_date', 'created'
        )
```

**Description**
The issue was the DRF expects a dict like object from `contact` field since you are defined a ***`nested serializer`***. So, I removed the ***nested relationship*** dynamically with the help of overriding the `__init__()` method

Comment: I tried it but, still the same issue. The printed `print(self.context)` before `if` and prints `{'request': <rest_framework.request.Request object at 0x106156278>, 'format': None, 'view': <transactions.views.AmountGivenViewSet object at 0x1060fb780>}` with **POST** call while `{}` for **GET** call.

Comment: oh..my bad.....It should be **`self.context['view'].action != 'create'`**

Answer (score 0):

For those who got here but have relatively simple serializers, this error can also occur when the request data is malformed, in my case JSON encoded twice.

The serializer will decode the JSON, but as it is encoded twice `request.data` will still be a string. The error therefore makes sense as a "dictionnary" was expected, but we still have a "string".

You can check the output of the following to confirm whether this is the issue you are experiencing:

```py
print(type(request.data))  # Should be <class 'dict'>
```